Trouble installing dgl with pytorch compatibility
System Info:
Ubuntu 22.04.5, x86_64, jammy_jellyfish
CUDA GPU GA106 GeForce RTX 3060
gcc 11.4.0
NVIDIA driver version 560.35.03
CUDA version 12.6
When installing dgl after installation of pytorch, dgl will not install.
Tried installing the latest versions of pytorch and dgl, and keeps showing error in installation of dgl.

Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you paste the error you get and explain which steps you have followed to install pytorch and DGL ?

Hi @trialNerror, I was able to install, after some trial and error!
However, had to use downgraded versions.
used older Pytorch version:
conda install pytorch==2.2.1 torchvision==0.17.1 pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia — to install pytorch 2.2.1 with cuda 12.1
had problem with numpy, installed numpy again,
pip install "“numpy<2”
installed dgl 2.4.0,
pip install dgl -f https://data.dgl.ai/wheels/torch-2.2/cu121/repo.html
This is working for the time being.
